# CSS Position Absolute Z-Index Issue

Tags: css, z-index

I have a form that uses a div that is positions over some input elements.  For some reason, those input elements are above the positioned div, even though the div has a high z-index.  Really not sure why this is happening, as the input fields don't even use absolute positioning, so I would think they would never be on top of another element.

Example (Click into Person, Status or Residence field):
http://www.puc.edu/puc-life/funnybook/little-black-funnybook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't even need to set a high stacking order for the .item .answer selector, at least in the Gecko engine. Try removing the position and z-index and see if it's consistent x-browser?

Edit: Ah I forgot I had applied position:relative to the div.item element, can you try toggling that when it shows up and unset it when you hide it?

That or leave position:relative on all div.items through external CSS and toggle the z-index to be '2' when the stuff pops ups and back to auto when it's hidden.

Comment: I removed z-index: 1000 from .item .answer and this did the trick. Not sure why it was there in the first place...

Comment: Looks like IE7 still have an issue.  Now that it is fixed in Safari/FF, gotta fix it in IE7.  Ideas?

Comment: Which solution did you choose? You applied position relative to div.items? If so, try toggling the z-index to be higher when the pop up occurs.

Comment: I didn't do either.  I just removed the z-index from .item .answer.  Right now I am focused on getting the div to show above the input element in IE7.  Tried adding position:relative but that does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is the solution but it does not work proper with youtube movie iframe, for that you would have to use wmode='transparent'